# How To Find Child Object and set is own criteria/condition?

Tags: unity, 2d

I am Making 2D Game.

I Apply a Two Tag On Multiple Child Game Object..

Crate A Empty Game Object and Put Script Obstacle.cs and Rigidbody2d.

Child GameObject -> Static OnTriggerEnter2D

```
Obstacle.cs

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (Transform item in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            if (item.tag == "someobstacleslow")  //7 child game object find successfully
            {
                Debug.Log("someobstacleslow:" + item.tag);
            }

            if (item.tag == "someobstaclefast") //4 child game object find successfully
            {
                Debug.Log("movefastobstacle:" + item.tag);

            }
     }
```

Referance:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7nnM.jpg

I want to some obstacleslow is going slow and someobstaclefast is going fast but nothing happens.

Output: all obstacle going very fasy?? what i miss my programme??

But Child GameObject not working its own condition?

```
Obstacle.cs

   float speed = 2.5f;                             //normal speed

    float movefastobjectspeed = 3f;                //fast spped

    void Update()    
    {
        goTopToDown();
    }

    void goTopToDown()
    {
            foreach (Transform item in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                if (item.tag == "someobstacleslow")   //issue here
                {
                    //move top to down object normal speed
                    transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime; 

                    Debug.Log("GameObject obstacle object:" + item.tag);
                    Debug.Log("inside obstacle object");

                }

                if (item.tag == "someobstaclefast") // issue here
                {
                    //move top to down object fast speed
                    transform.position += Vector3.down * movefastobjectspeed * Time.deltaTime;   

                    Debug.Log("GameObject movefast object:" + item.tag);
                    Debug.Log("inside movefast object");
                }

            }
    }
```

When My Obstacle Touch My Player then Ontrigger2d Is fire

```
Obstacle.cs

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            if (child.tag == "someobstacleslow" || child.tag == "someobstaclefast")
            {
                Debug.Log("chiildtag:" + child.tag);
                gameovertext.SetActive(true);

                StartCoroutine(gameover());
                Debug.Log("inside triggerfire");
            }
        }
    }
```

But Issue Is all obstacle going very fast(See in referance).I want to some obstacleslow is going slow and someobstaclefast is going fast but nothing happens.??help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the parent's transform. Instead change the children's transform.

```
void goTopToDown()
{
        foreach (Transform item in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
        {
            if (item.tag == "someobstacleslow")   //issue here
            {
                //Instead of 'trasnform'(parent's transform) you need 'item' (child's transform)
                item.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime

                Debug.Log("GameObject obstacle object:" + item.tag);
                Debug.Log("inside obstacle object");

            }

            if (item.tag == "someobstaclefast") // issue here
            {
                item.position += Vector3.down * movefastobjectspeed * Time.deltaTime;   

                Debug.Log("GameObject movefast object:" + item.tag);
                Debug.Log("inside movefast object");
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: thanks i m trying this issue last 2 days..Thankss.

Comment: i thing unity take transform.position is  a world position(means worldcoordinate) and transform.localposition is a child position(means childcoordinate) ?? can u clarify??

Comment: can i use ```transform.localposition``` because it relative to an object ?? can i replace this??

Comment: Yes, transform.localPosition is in local coordinates relative to THAT transform's parent. But if you use the local position of the parent of all obstacles you're not changing the obstacles individualy